# Update propertyName by TextBox's text only when the button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this XAML code:

```
<Window 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding propertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Save" Click="Add_Click" IsDefault="True" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I want to bind the `Name` textbox to the `propertyName` only when my `Save` button is clicked. The `propertyName` is declared in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` like this:

```
public string propertyName { get; set; }
```

Currently the code works but the buttons are useless, no matter which button(Save or Cancel) is clicked, the property already has updated. I am not using MVVM, does anybody have any idea on this? I'm looking for a XAML solution, if it is possible.

**The main question is:
Is there any way do to this in XAML only, if there is, so how? And if there is not any way, why should I use the Binding in this case at all, when I can simply set the property in my click event? Since I have just one property, I could simply use `propertyName = Name.Text;` in the click event of the button**

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="20"  Background="Green">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding propertyName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
        </TextBox>
        <ToggleButton Name="button1" Width="100" Content="save">
        </ToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Nice one. I'm not sure whether it's the best solution user-experience-wise, but does the trick nicely.

Comment: Thanks. But what is `Path=IsChecked` for Button??

Comment: the essential binding to your button state

Comment: So, where do you set the `propertyName`?

Comment: Good Question!: Answer: you just replace Value="button checked" by Value="{Binding propertyName, Mode=OneWay}" Use One-way binding if you have a getter only.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there any way to call the `Close()` method in xaml after this changes, so that I don't have to call it in code behind? i.e in  ToggleButton

Comment: what close() method ? There's hacky solutions using CDATA in xaml if you want C# in xaml. I would not recommend using CDATA.

Comment: Sorry but this line `Value="{Binding propertyName, Mode=OneWay}"` is not working!

Comment: I want to update propertyName in code behind, and also have tried with `OneWayToSource` but no luck.

Comment: It doesn't set the `propertyName`.

Comment: Correct. Look at the solution: It triggers the button state and gets your property. Nothing more. If you want to make your textbox input bind to a property, just add the binding like you had. There's two different use-cases actually. They should go along with each other.

Comment: yes i have added binding to my textbox itself, but the problem is that it changes the property with cancel button too!!!

Comment: the textbox trigger in the above sample binds to a specific button by the ElementName. 2ndly, OnewayToSource binding (setting your property when TextBox.Text changes) is probably what your looking for.

Comment: The more logic you want to add, the more trigger  code would be required in xaml, if you want to keep it in xaml. The next step are wpf behaviors, which attach to your UIElements, but are completely separated from your main application code.

Comment: If your requirement is to NOT use MVVM and you already use code behind AND you want it to do more than one thing... Why not just use code-behind in the Save Click event to grab the current Text from the TextBox, set the property and then close it?